# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass in Rails 3, only in RSpec test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I was getting this error, but only in tests, not in development or production. It was related to a model representing a legacy database table that did not conform to basic Rails conventions for table names, as it was named **LUM_User** and had a primary key of **UserID**.

I finally discovered that somehow the test version of the table had been created with the name **lum_user** instead of **LUM_User**. Once I fixed this, the error was gone.

Comment: No, I just wanted to document this. It took me 3 hours to figure out and no amount of searching helped. This way, maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Answered in the original post: check the table case and make sure it matches what you have set in the **set_table_name** statement.